# Netsuite - Check a box from a Saved Search button

Tags: button, search, netsuite, suitescript

Some progress made here thanks to answer from Suitestar.

Managed to make a suitelet which performs the task. However:

1. Only works by putting an absolute item ID in the script itself.
   The var rec_ID to pull through the ID of the item from the search does not work. I get a 'Missing Argument' error.
2. Opens a blank window and the saved search page defaults to a blanket item search. I just want a popup to say 'Approved' and for the search to stay the same.
3. How do I pull through the field ID from the search as well?

Suite URL and code below:

<button onclick=window.open(`/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=602&deploy=1&rec_id=2958`);>Approve

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType Suitelet
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define (['N/record'], function (record) {
    function onRequest(scriptContext) {
        
        var rec_Id=scriptContext.request.parameters.rec_Id; //getting parameter

        var itemRecObj= record.load({ type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, id: '2958', isDynamic:true });

        itemRecObj.setValue({ fieldId: 'custitem_aamac_custom_approved', value: true });

        itemRecObj.save();
    }

return {
    
    onRequest: onRequest
};
    
    });
```

Comment: The button will open a new window with a Suitelet which you can read about in the docs.

Comment: Thanks bk. I'm assuming I can execute a workflow from a suitelet using the N/workflow. The issues is I have 96 of these checkboxes and need to add in some conditional parameters. I don't mind having to create 96 actions on a single workflow, bit I'm loathe to have to create 96 workflows dependent on which checkbox I want checked. Also I'm assuming that as the item ID is in the button action that the workflow will run on this item without me having to input the internal id in the initiate workflow script?

Comment: This button is not a workflow button. The receiving suitelet would need to pass the item id to the initiate workflow. IMO by the time you've entered and debugged 96 workflow actions you could have written a script 10 times over and a script is way more maintainable.  -- inspectable, searchable, easier to modify and test if one of your conditions changes etc.

Comment: I agree. But I'm a scripting novice. I have created nearly 200 workflows. I have written maybe half a dozen scripts and they are simplistic. Can you help me with 1 piece of information. Is it possible for the Suitelet called by this button to contain enough functionality to get the item id from the button click, go to the item record 
and modify a checkbox on the item and then display a popup box which says 'approved' ? I would need the Suitelet to choose which box to check based on some CASE WHEN conditioning in the formula on the Saved Search itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a backend logic in **suitelet script** for checking the check box.

- Load the record with internal id of item
- Use setValue with value "true" for check box fieldID .
- And then save the record.
- deploy the suitelet in release mode, copy the **external url** put it in button onclick function.as in screenshot you did.
- pass the parameter using **&rec_Id** something like this in the last of url

https://tstdrv1911674.extforms.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=6030&deploy=1&compid=TSTDRV1911674&h=e3ac9c7644c25b4dded1&rec_Id=

and get the parameter in suitelet script using

**var rec_Id=scriptContext.request.parameters.rec_Id;**    //getting parameter

**var itemRecObj= record.load({
type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
id: rec_Id,
isDynamic:true
});**

**itemRecObj.setValue({
fieldId: 'checkboxfieldId',
value: true
});**

**itemRecObj.save();**

Comment: Thank you Suitestar. This has got me started. I managed to get the script to check a box however I am still having some issues in pulling the record id from the search and I also need to figure out how to put a dynamic field id in as well. Have posted code above.

Comment: Hi @TheIronKing , You have already used the correct code in last post for dynamic record id.    let me share with you again      '<button onclick="window.open(`/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=5737&deploy=1&compid=TSTDRV1911674&h=f9329046621d18caa232&rec_Id=' || {internalid} || '`);">Approve</button>'                                                                       Use this in saved search and please vote 1 for my answer so that it could be helpful to everyone.

Comment: @TheIronKing , Let me know for any thing else.

Comment: Thank you Suitestar. I have uprated your answer and ticked it as the official answer. However I am now having another problem. I need to discern between which check box to check. But the use of If statements is not functioning as expected. I know you have already helped me but if you could spare the time to look at my latest question I would be very grateful, link is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209311/netsuite-suitescript-chain-of-if-statements-always-returns-same-result