# Netsuite Suitescript - Chain of If statements always returns same result

Tags: if-statement, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet which I have managed to get working. however there is an issue.

I have a button on a saved search which is loading parameters.

I need to check a different box on an item record dependent on the values passed.

However it seems that only the top If statement is operated on regardless of the name of the field_id that get's passed.

What am I missing about the way these statements work?

The button link is here:

'<button onclick="window.open(`/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=602&deploy=1&compid=********&field_id=' || {systemnotes.field} || ' &rec_id=' || {internalid} || '`);>Approve'

So it the system notes field I am trying to split the checkbox action on.

The actual script is here:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType Suitelet
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define (['N/record'], function (record) {
    function onRequest(scriptContext) {
        
        var rec_id=scriptContext.request.parameters.rec_id; //getting parameter
        
        var field_id=scriptContext.request.parameters.field_id; //getting parameter

        var itemRecObj= record.load({ type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, id: rec_id, isDynamic:true });
        
        if(field_id='custom field 1'){

        itemRecObj.setValue({ fieldId: 'checkbox1', value: true });

        itemRecObj.save();
        }
        
        else if(field_id='custom field 2'){

        itemRecObj.setValue({ fieldId: 'checkbox2', value: true });

        itemRecObj.save();
        }
        
        
    }

return {
    
    onRequest: onRequest
};
    
    });
```

Only the custom field 1 statement is acted on, if I swap them and put the custom field 2 details above then only checkbox 2 is checked.

I need to create a substantial list of these statements and only check the box where the field_id matches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a single `=`. You should be using double `==` (`field_id == 'custom field 1'`)

Comment: Thanks W.S. - When I tried this it then never checks any of the boxes. Do I need to somehow further define the var field_id within the if statement itself?

Comment: Okay, mystery solved, I had a space in the link on the button on the actual saved search, this meant the == was never matching up. Thank W.S., and Suitestar and BKnights. Onto the next problem :-)